# App creation with AmpersandJs and Database connectivity

Tags: node.js, ampersand.js

I am creating a nodejs app and as per clients suggestion trying to implement it in AmpersandJs. I have installed framework and created application by following documentation [&js installation](http://ampersandjs.com/docs#ampersand-installation).

The app is running with some sample data 
[image]

I found that the sample data is coming from `ampersand-app` module from an `index.js` file.

But I want to do database connectivity with it -- How should I achieve this? I have Googled but not found any good link for it.

Did `&js` is good choice to develop application or it is for an specific type of projects?

Answer (score 0):

> But I want to do database connectivity with it -- How should I achieve this?

Ampersand.js is running in the browser. If you want to access data stored in a database you have two options:

1. Request data from a database running on a server somewhere accessible over the network.  In this case you want to use the `url` property of models/collections
2. Use an in-browser database (maybe you want to have look at `pouchdb` as API)

> Did `&js` is good choice to develop applications?

Definitely yes!